# Is there any built in Events in asp.net which triggers for all PageLoads?

Tags: asp.net

After Completing My asp Project I came up with a new requirement. For this, I have to Execute some code in all page Load events. Can I get an event for all those page loads? I can't use Session_start of Global.asax since it will include WebHandlers with Session State. Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could place the code in Master, but your request is too vague. Also you may inherit same Page.

Comment: As stated above, the Page_Load in the Master would be best here if you're using one.

Comment: No master Pages. @ChrisDixon

Comment: How many pages do you have? Best bet here is to either create one, or create a BasePage and all your pages inherit from that. It may be time costly, but worth it in the long run.

Comment: Your decision may not provide flexibility in ur project for long run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session start would not be suitable as it will only be fired when a users is given a new session rather than each time a page is loaded.

There are several options, including using a base page which all of you pages inherit from. This will mean you need to remember to hook this up to all pages.

My suggestion would be to write an http module which is fired for all aspx page loads.

You will need to create a module which implements System.Web.IHttpModule.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        application.EndRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<h1><font color=red>" +
                "HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request" +
                "</font></h1><hr>");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Then hook it up in the web.config as per the example here.

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule" />
</httpModules>
```

You would need to check the context.Request.Path property in the module to exclude any request where the path did't meet your criteria (i.e. not ending aspx).

More info here. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20200618051219/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/demos/printPage.aspx?path=/articles/011404-1.aspx

Comment: Not sure how that answers the question. It does not handle PageLoad event. It is just an equivalent of handling Application_BeginRequest in global asax.

Comment: In addition it won't work if a page has another extension (not "aspx"). This can happen for example in case of routing.

Comment: My impression was the OP simply wanted to fire some code each time a page was hit. OP, if you could give us some more information on your use case (what code is it you want to fire for each page load?) then we could supply a better answer. @Egor4eg - This is true, routing / url rewriting could cause issues. You could get around this by extending the logic for what constitutes a page (using a balck list instead of a white list etc) or using a base page. Once again, a use case will help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2):

You keep a Base Page and Inherit it from all aspx pages. In this way you can keep the logic centralized.

**Example**

**Aspx Page**

```
public partial class MyAspxPage : BasePage
{

}
```

**Base Page**

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

You should also leave AutoEventWireup set to false.

Comment: No. Keep the load event in Base Page and logic in it's load handler. Don's do it in individual handler of aspx page.

Comment: @SubinJacob Difference between Base Page and HttpHandler is that HttpHandler will execute page load logic for your all application pages and this may execute it even for those which are not suppose to do it and at the other hand BasePage will execute for those pages which you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here whould be to create a custom base page class which implements PageLoad and then inherit all your pages from it.

Something like:

```
public abstract class BasePage: Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // your code
   }
}
```

You can register base page class in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <!-- ... -->
    <pages pageBaseType="MyWeb.UI.BasePage" />
  <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```

Comment: `MyWeb.UI.PageBase` or `MyWeb.UI.BasePage`

Comment: `Error 21 Could not load type 'MyWeb.UI.BasePage'.  
`

Comment: Do you have the same namespace as in my example? ('MyWeb.UI')

Comment: I added a new cs file and no namespace. Should I add one?

Comment: If you added a file without namespace it would go to a default namespace. To find it you should do right click on your project in Visual Studio, go to Properties and then Application tab.

Comment: There isn't any app tabs. And it is website properties

Comment: Even after adding a new namespace the same problem exists.